# Change display product woocommerce

Tags: css, woocommerce

I want to change the style of showing product this https://i.stack.imgur.com/bH2Vo.jpg to this https://i.stack.imgur.com/AMcMp.jpg

Link my website http://douxeclair.ro/magazin-2/
Link target webiste https://gracecc.ro/onlineshop/

How can i do this?

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to change the look, you can do it with inspecting the elements on your page, find the classes or ids, and add something like that to your style.css

```
.product-buttons a:last-child {
    float: right;
    background-color: sandybrown;
    padding: 5px 20px;
    border-radius: 8px;
}
```

If you want to rearrange the elements you will have to edit the template of this card element.

EDIT: I think/hope you are interessted in learning how to do such things, I will describe the basic concept.

In your css your target the box with the image and informations in it. You will hide this information on default. If the box is hovered, the information will show up.

So we first set the buttons in the box to be invisible by setting the opacity to zero:

```
.product-grid-view .product-buttons {
    opacity: 0;
}
```

If we hover the parent element (product-grid-view), the product-buttons in it will change to fully visible, opacity of the max of one:

```
.product-grid-view:hover .product-buttons {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

You can add a transition to make it look smooth:

```
.product-grid-view .product-buttons {
    transition: opacity .3s ease-in-out;
}
```

This should give you something to start with.

EDIT 2:

If you want to have the buttons to appear when the image is hovered, you can make use of the **CSS all next siblings selector**.

```
.product-grid-view .product-images:hover ~ .product-buttons {
     opacity: 1;
}
```

You still need the css definitions to set the opacity on default to zero and to set the transition. So you have to replace the second of the three code blocks I postet in my last edit.

Comment: i want to delete the box and remaining only image with hover, add to cart and price

Comment: I edited my answer and gave you a basic concept of how to achieve something like this

Comment: Great, thanks. But i want a hover on image. On i put the mouse on image, then text appear under this.

Comment: I added the code to my answer how you can target the image. It is done with the CSS all enxt siblings selector. Please mark my answer as the accepted answer if you are happy with it. Thank you.